# Implementing comparative testing between two versions of project

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a python project, the folder structure looks like this:

```
projectA/
    scripts/ -> contains many modules
    projectA/ -> contains classes which import modules
    test/ -> tests for testing scripts update using classes
```

Classes can be instantiated and the instances perform the intended tasks by sequential functional calls to the imported modules (for given arguments to the class object). 
Classes import the scripts folder by these lines:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'scripts/') # execution happens always from root.
```

I'm working on a test framework, which can test two versions of scripts folder and provide me final result as follows:

```
version    | result1 | result2 | ....
version1   | 10      | 2       | ....
version1.1 | 11      | 1       | ....
```

For achieving this, I can update the classes to import different `scripts/` folder (Eg. scripts/ , test/scripts/) during constructor call, do operations, and finally join the results. I can import the scripts folder in `__init__` and access it using class variables through out the class lifetime. But, this is not a good practice.

Is there another way to implement this type of test framework? Please feel free to suggest any standard process of doing this, which may involve significant changes in my implementation.

Comment: If just want to update your project, you could use a git repository (GITHUB, GILAB, BITBUCKET) and run a bash script that pulls all the new files exactaly as you described, without the need to implement anything. Here is a more in depth explanation on hot git works https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/

Comment: My project resides in Git, as I understand, what you are trying to say is to the push the new modules and do the test again. This is not what I meant, the problem described is not about CI process. It's about creating a test framework. For testing a different set of modules I don't really need to use Git at all, if I have to manual change the scripts and test it twice. The problem is to have a test framework, which can test two different set of versions of the scripts folder in automated fashion where you just need to copy the scripts folder with your changes, and execute just one script.